# goerli Eth is not showing in my metamask wallet testnet

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, metamask, wallets, goerli

i having been trying for last few weeks to add goerli faucet it shows that transaction is been done but by balance shows zero also tried on sepolia testnet but same problem dont know what to do
have been building a project and need faucets can anyone helpout

-0x51e199f1ec3030B4610007C29ab3D272af91Dfd6

Answer (score 1):

Which Faucet are you using? because there is no transaction on this address.

Try these Faucets:

1. [Alchemy Faucet](https://goerlifaucet.com/)
2. [Chainlink Faucet](https://faucets.chain.link/)